# Print number of post (in reverse)

Tags: php, posts, pages

I'm trying to input the numer of the post next to it, but in the reverse order, which means

not

1 
2
3
4

but

4
3
2
1
.

I have succeeded into doing it in the "right" order with this :

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

<?php echo $wp_query->current_post + 1; ?>
```

but I can't figure out how to do the opposite. Morethough, when I have my posts in several pages, it breaks aka

PAGE 1 : 1234
PAGE 2 : 1234 (should be 5678)

I have tried this :

```
<?php echo $wp_query->found_posts - $wp_query->current_post ?>
```

which inputs 8765
and then the next page 8765 instead of 4321...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To print a decreasing counter for the main home query, without sticky posts, you can try:

```
// current page number - paged is 0 on the home page, we use 1 instead
$_current_page  = is_paged() ?  get_query_var( 'paged', 1 ) : 1; 

// posts per page
$_ppp           = get_query_var( 'posts_per_page', get_option( 'posts_per_page' ) );

// current post index on the current page
$_current_post  = $wp_query->current_post;

// total number of found posts
$_total_posts   = $wp_query->found_posts;

// Decreasing counter    
echo $counter = $_total_posts - ( $_current_page - 1 ) * $_ppp - $_current_post;
```

**Example:**

For total of 10 posts, with 4 posts per page, the decreasing counter should be:

```
Page 1: 
    10 - ( 1 - 1 ) * 4 - 0 = 10
    10 - ( 1 - 1 ) * 4 - 1 = 9
    10 - ( 1 - 1 ) * 4 - 2 = 8
    10 - ( 1 - 1 ) * 4 - 3 = 7

Page 2: 
    10 - ( 2 - 1 ) * 4 - 0 = 6
    10 - ( 2 - 1 ) * 4 - 1 = 5
    10 - ( 2 - 1 ) * 4 - 2 = 4
    10 - ( 2 - 1 ) * 4 - 3 = 3

Page 3: 
    10 - ( 3 - 1 ) * 4 - 0 = 2
    10 - ( 3 - 1 ) * 4 - 1 = 1
```

or:

```
Page 1: 10,9,8,7
Page 2: 6,5,4,3
Page 3: 2,1
```

**Update:**

To support sticky posts we can adjust the above counter with:

```
// Decreasing counter    
echo $counter = $_total_posts
    + $sticky_offset 
    - ( $_current_page - 1 ) * $_ppp 
    - $_current_post;
```

where we define:

```
$sticky_offset =  is_home() && ! is_paged() && $_total_posts > $_ppp 
    ? $wp_query->post_count - $_ppp 
    : 0;
```

Note that there can be three cases of sticky posts:

1. all sticky posts come from the first (home) page. (The number of displayed posts on the homepage is the same as without sticky posts).
2. negative of 1)
3. mixed 1) and 2)

Our adjustments should handle all three cases.

Comment: It worked ! Thank you for the answer and the great explanations!

Comment: Glad it helped @Dikeneko

Answer (score 0):

Strange question. You can create a secondary query or run a hook into [pre_get_posts](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/pre_get_posts/) but the general idea is you would [order by ID](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters) in Descending Order:

```
$query = new WP_Query( array(
    'orderby' => array( 'ID' => 'DESC' ),
) );
```

You could also probably run [array_reverse()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reverse.php) on the original query's `posts` array but I tend not to mess with the original WP Query Object.

Comment: I do strange designs :) 
But the ID is not 1 2 3 4 etc, sometimes it's 2 4 14 38 for example ?

Answer (score 0):

Here you go...

```
<?php
$per_page = 4;
$post_query = new WP_Query('post_type=post&posts_per_page='.$per_page);
$total_found_posts = $post_query->found_posts;

if($total_found_posts >= $per_page){
    $count_from  = $per_page;
} elseif ($total_found_posts < $per_page){
    $count_from  = $total_found_posts;
}

if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();

the_title();

echo 'Serial #'. $count_from--; 

endwhile;
endif;
wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but that didn't work... on both page 1 and 2, it shows 4321 :/